# Jquery: Clearing summary form input values

Tags: jquery

I'm sure this is a simple fix, but I haven't figured it out yet after research.

I have a multi-page input form that presents a summary page of the data from the input fields.  The input fields have a  default string which describes the input field and is basically the 'id' attribute.  When the user clicks into the input field to enter data, the default data disappears and the new data is entered.  If the user makes no entry into the input field, the default data remains as it should.  The summary page displays all of the inputs from the form fields, including the default data. The problem I'm having is figuring out how clear the default data prior to displaying the summary page.  I'm sure it's something simple I'm overlooking, but I need another set of sharp eyes and jquery acumen.

The summary form has two tables embedded in divs side-by-side.  I'm using the `nth-child()` method to select the correct `td` to display the data.

Psuedo code logic:  "If an input field contains `attr('id')`, then clear the field; 
else, display the field."

I have used `.val("")`, `.val()`, `.text("")` and `.html("")` to clear the field to no avail.  I need some professional help. :-)

```
    //prepare the fourth step
    var fieldsLeft = new Array(
        $('#firstname').val(),
        $('#middlename').val(),
        $('#lastname').val(),
        $('#address').val(),
        $('#city').val(),
        $('#zip').val(),
        $('#dob').val(),
        $('#ssn').val()
    )

    var fieldsRight = new Array(
        $('#homephone').val(),
        $('#workphone').val(),
        $('#cellphone').val(),
        $('#employer').val(),
        $('#emergency').val(),
        $('#relationship').val(),
        $('#phoneday').val(),
        $('#phonenight').val(),
        $('#email').val()
        );

    var sumLeft = $('#fourth_step #leftSummary tr');
    sumLeft.each(function() {
        var valueL = $(this).val();
        if ( valueL == fieldsLeft[$(this).attr('id')]) {
            $(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').val('');
        } else {
            $(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').html(fieldsLeft[$(this).index()])
        }
    });

    var sumRight = $('#fourth_step #rightSummary tr');
    sumRight.each(function() {
        var valueR = $(this).val();
        if ( valueR == fieldsRight[$(this).attr('id')]) {
            $(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').val('');
        } else {
            $(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').html(fieldsRight[$(this).index()])
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hey, it'd be useful to see the html (maybe on a jsfiddle), also, what do you mean exactly with "clear the field" ?

Comment: I thought about using jsfiddle...why don't I just go ahead and do that.  Give me a few.

Comment: Oh yeah, by 'clear the field', I'm basically saying make the field blank so it does not appear in the summary page.

Comment: so hiding it would be good enough for you?

Comment: That would be good enough for me.  So you're suggesting a hide method?

Comment: indeed, give me a moment to put an answer together...

Comment: Normally you should be able to clear "td"s by using .text("")
But I guess the jsfiddle will help understand better

Comment: I agree with @DonBarry usually I'd use something like `.text('')` or `.html('')`, but if hiding/showing works for you, see my answer...

Comment: Ok, here is the jfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/brohjoe/hHcAp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work using placeholders.  The default text in the input fields disappear when the form is submitted for the summary view, as I had wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If `.hide()` works for what you want, you can try something like this:

```
//prepare the fourth step
var fieldsLeft = 
$('#firstname, #middlename, #lastname, #address, #city, #zip, #dob, #ssn').map(function(){
   return $(this).val();
});

var fieldsRight = 
$('#homephone,#workphone,#cellphone,#employer,#emergency,#relationship,#phoneday,#phonenight,#email').map(function(){
    return $(this).val();
});

var sumLeft = $('#fourth_step #leftSummary tr');
sumLeft.each(function() {
    var valueL = $(this).val();
    if ( valueL == fieldsLeft[$(this).attr('id')]) {
        $(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').hide();
    } else {
        $(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').show();
    }
});

var sumRight = $('#fourth_step #rightSummary tr');
sumRight.each(function() {
    var valueR = $(this).val();
    if ( valueR == fieldsRight[$(this).attr('id')]) {
        $(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').hide();
    } else {
        $(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').show();
    }
});
```

Also I recommend the usage of `.map()` to make the arrays (assuming your inputs are in the same order as your current arrays)

Comment: Ok, let me try your solution darkajax.  Be back.

Comment: @brohjoe Ok, just check it out because somehow not all the code showed up, I've just edited it...

Comment: Apparently, it's still not working. The '.hide()' method is hiding everything, all the fields.  The summary is blank.